# React Native FlatList onEndReached not called if number of items is not enough to make it scrollable

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to implement an infinite scroll mechanism where I fetch data from the server and feed it into a FlatList. To do this, I decided on a number of items that will be loaded per fetch(5 in my case).

The fetch call is made when `onEndReached` is called. I am having an issue however, depending on the data that I receive from the server, the initial data might be small and the 5 items that I get are not enough to fully fill the FlatList. (Basically, FlatList elements vary in size, and in some cases 5 items are super small and it does not fill the entire height of the FlatList).

Well, in this case, the end of the FlatList is clearly visible but `onEndReached` is not being called and so my next fetch does not happen.

I tried multiple values for `onEndReachedThreshold` but it still does not get called. Is `onEndReached` suppose to get called if there is not enough height to even make the FlatView scrollable or I am approaching this issue from the wrong angle?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly. But if the user can see the bottom of the list, isn't it normal he/she assumes that's the end? So I think you have to automatically call fetch until the screen has been filled first, before enabling user interactions.

Comment: As per my knowledge, the flat list is created on the bases of the scroll view component
and the onEndReached prop is one of the props of the ScrollView component so if you don't have such a list that shows the scrolling then the method doesn't call.

Comment: @cltsang I see your point but how can I check wether the screen have been filled up or not. Depending on what I get from the server, the first 5 items of the data can fill up the screen and make it scrollable or they can`t. Any ideas how to check for this?

Comment: @saik have you tried using https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onviewableitemschanged ?

Comment: @cltsang I am aware of that one but I am not sure how onViewableItemsChanged can help me determine whether the added items caused the FlatList to become scrollable or not.